# Get information from one column to another

Tags: r, vector, character, match

I started working with R recently and I am trying to find a solution for the following problem:

I have a `data.frame` with several columns. One of them contains file names with all the information needed. Example: "13_07_26_SpeciesA_Genotype22_Column1Row2"

I want to create new columns with the information from the name. For example a genotype column with "22", a row column with "2" and so on.

I could do this with `grepl` and `gsub` individually as shown below:

```
 files <- c("13_12_26_Species_Genotype22_Column1Row2", 
       "15_12_26_Species_Genotype01_Column2Row5")  
weights <- c(20,40)           
spreadsheet <- data.frame(files,weights)  
GT22 <- grepl("Genotype22", spreadsheet$files)    
spreadsheet$GT <- gsub("TRUE","22",GT22)
```

But I have to check for >1000 genotypes in many files from different dates etc. So I tried to compare a vector with all possible Genotypes e.g.

```
 gt.list <- paste("Genotype",01:1000,sep="")
```

with the spreadsheet$files column using functions like `match()` or `apply()`. But I have not been able to get it running. The Genotypes are not in order so I want to compare every cell of the "files" column with all the entries from my vector and then write all the matches in a new column (...22,01,...). I could rewrite this function for the different information.

I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: A minor point you will need to address is that `paste("Genotype",01:1000,sep="")` will not give you what you need - it will return 01 as 1 and 2 and so on, so you will get `"Genotype1","Genotype2"` etc

Comment: Thanks for that comment. I did realise this but figured the query itself would be me main problem right now. Is there an option to change 1 into 01 or 0001 and so on?

Comment: Probably, but I'm not aware of it. Easiest for this situation is just to do a bit more typing!! :-) `c( paste("Genotype0",1:9,sep="") , paste("Genotype",10:1000,sep="") )`

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed. At least one problem solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DF <- data.frame(
  do.call(rbind,strsplit(files,'_',fixed=T)),
  weights,
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
DF$GT <- substr(DF[,5],9,nchar(DF[,5]))
DF$Row <- do.call(rbind,strsplit(DF[,6],'Row',fixed=T))[,2]

#   X1 X2 X3      X4         X5          X6 weights GT Row
# 1 13 12 26 Species Genotype22 Column1Row2      20 22   2
# 2 15 12 26 Species Genotype01 Column2Row5      40 01   5
```

I am not a regex wiz.